# SAML 2.0 on Android using Duo Access Gateway

Tags: java, android, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

My company uses Duo Access Gateway as our SAML 2.0 Identity Provider.

I have an Android native application in which I need to implement SSO. I've tried searching for guides/tutorials on how to accomplish this but have been unsuccessful.

Is there a way to do this, possibly using Chrome Custom Tabs?

Comment: I did this a while ago using a WebView with a custom WebViewClient, overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading. When the response from the IdP comes in I catch it and deal with the SAML in the Android app

Comment: @codebrane Any chance you could share your code? I'm completely lost as to how to implement this.